# Finding solution for a combination of arrays

Tags: math

I'm hoping someone might be able to point me into the right direction.

Given a list of several items I need to find the total count for each item that adds up to the solution.

Lets say I need to find solution {9, 2, 6}, I need to figure out which items would add up to the solution, items can repeat as well.

```
item1 {2 , 5, 6}
item2 {9, -1, 2}
item3 {6, 19, 12}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on what you're asking but I'll give a couple of options based on different interpretations after reading your question through a couple of times.

1.) If you're just looking for the same sum, then you would (in a loop) add up the elements of the array and then compare that sum to the sum of the solution.

2.) If you're looking for an array that has the same elements in the same order as the solution, then you would just compare each element and check if they are the same.

3.) If you want to find multiple arrays that add up to the solution, then you could create another array and use it to keep track of the values, stopping when you reach the solution and using some sort of check variable (maybe another array) to record which arrays add up to the solution.